# generate and output all possible combinations, from three List<String> only once per unique item

Tags: java, string, arraylist, combinatorics

I'm trying to generate all possible combinations of sentences. As variables I have two Strings, one String will be the subject, e.g. `health` and one will be an object, such as `fruit`, but then I will have a `List<String>` of values associated with one "head" word, so in keeping with the two components just mentioned, they would be associated with the list `[improve, change, alter, modify]`. I want to generate all possible combinations of these sentences and add each one to the `List<Sentences>` with something like:

```
Sentence example_sentence = new Sentence(verb, object, subject);
sentences.add(example_sentence);
```

Right now the larger function in which this is taking place looks like this:

```
public Sentence dataPreprocessing(String raw_subject, String raw_object, String raw_verb, List<Sentence> sentences) throws IOException {
    WordNet wordnet = new WordNet();
    String verb = wordnet.getStem(raw_verb);
    String object = wordnet.getStem(raw_object);        
    String subject = wordnet.getStem(raw_subject);
    List<String> verb_hypernym_container = new ArrayList<>();       
    verb_hypernym_container = wordnet.getHypernyms(verb, POS.VERB);
    //wordnet.getHypernyms(this.object, POS.NOUN);  
    //wordnet.getHypernyms(this.subject, POS.NOUN); 
    Sentence return_sentence = new Sentence( verb, object, subject );
    return return_sentence;
}
```

How can I most effectively achieve this goal of generating all possible sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a fixed number of lists, the simplest way is to just use nested loops:

```
List<Sentence> sentences = new ArrayList<>();

for(String verb_hypernym : wordnet.getHypernyms(verb, POS.VERB))
    for(String object_hypernym : wordnet.getHypernyms(object, POS.NOUN))
        for(String subject_hypernym : wordnet.getHypernyms(subject, POS.NOUN))
            sentences.add(new Sentence(verb_hypernym, object_hypernym, subject_hypernym));

return sentences;
```

Or, to avoid calling `getHypernyms` more often than necessary:

```
List<String> verb_hypernyms = wordnet.getHypernyms(verb, POS.VERB);
List<String> object_hypernyms = wordnet.getHypernyms(object, POS.NOUN);
List<String> subject_hypernyms = wordnet.getHypernyms(subject, POS.NOUN);


for(String verb_hypernym : verb_hypernyms)
    for(String object_hypernym : object_hypernyms)
        for(String subject_hypernym : subject_hypernyms)
            sentences.add(new Sentence(verb_hypernym, object_hypernym, subject_hypernym));

return sentences;
```

Comment: that's generating the same sentence more than once per list, is it possible to use a similar strucutre but keep it to only once per list?

Comment: @Joao.da.Silva what do you mean, one per list?

Comment: as in i'd not like to generate the same words in the same combination in one list more than one time

Comment: @Joao.da.Silva that shouldn't happen unless some of your hypernym lists contain the same word more than once.

Comment: @João.da.Silva if you mean the final list of sentence must not contain duplicates, then the simplest thing would be to make it a set rather than a list.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a list of nouns and verbs you could use streams to return a list of sentences. This also gives you a chance to remove any duplicates, sort or anything else you need to do to the stream.

```
List<Sentence> sentences = subjectList.stream()
        .flatMap(object -> verbList.stream()
            .flatMap(verb -> objectList.stream()
                .map(subject -> new Sentence(object, verb, subject))))
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: but could i  do it with three lists, one of `verbs` one of `objects` and one of `subjects`?